# My iphone 5c won't turn on, it just uzzes while plugged in

Tags: iphone

I recently fell on my iPhone while it was in my back pocket. The screen wasn't cracked but it refused to show the home screen. All the same noises were present (i.e; siri, charging). I tried a hard reset and now it won't turn on or light up at all and it buzzes constantly while on the charger. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

While the glass did not crack it is highly likely that the digitizer itself was broken. It's a little uncommon for this to happen but I've fixed my fair share of phones like this. You need a new screen. (Full screen replacement(digitizer and glass))

Comment: At least. And maybe more